# Waiting for a fileReader to finish before continuing

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, filereader

I have this code that I use to split a blob into fragments and it works as intended. But to my knowledge, the fileReader is async and my code continues before the entire blob can be converted to fragments and pushed in the fragmentArray. Is there any way to wait for the fragmentArray to be fully populated by the fragments before the code continues execution?

```
 var file = new Blob([SOME BLOB]);
 var fragmentArray = [];
 var chunkSize = 16384;

                var sliceFile = function (offset) {
                    var reader = new window.FileReader();
                    reader.onload = (function () {
                        return function (e) {
                            fragmentArray.push(e.target.result);
                            if (file.size > offset + e.target.result.byteLength) {
                                window.setTimeout(sliceFile, 0, offset + chunkSize);
                            }
                        };
                    })(file);
                    var slice = file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(slice);
                };
                sliceFile(0);
```

Comment: Put the code that is supposed to wait in the `else` branch of your `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick.